# Validating view form having two models at same time using Entityframework and mvc4,

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating mvc4 web where I need to login or register at same view page (as per design). And I am using EntityFramework. I am able to store my data and even retrieve them but
view form does not shows validation(as I am using Model Which contains two more models plz check the model for details)
I want my view form to show validation errors such as "Email Field is Required" which is suppose to happen automatically by Framework. please help...

### HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LoginOrRegisterDemo.Models;

namespace LoginOrRegisterDemo.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public void Register(User user)
    {
        //Models.User user = new Models.User();
        //TryUpdateModel(user);
        UserContext userContext = new UserContext();
        userContext.users.Add(user);
        userContext.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect("Show_Users");
    }
    public ActionResult Show_Users()
    {
        UserContext userContext= new UserContext();
        IEnumerable<User> users = userContext.users.ToList();

        return View(users);
    }
}
}
```

### ViewForms are

### Index.cshtml

```
@model LoginOrRegisterDemo.Models.UserModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Home")) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>IUser</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.iuser.EmailId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.iuser.EmailId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.iuser.EmailId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.iuser.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.iuser.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.iuser.Password)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Home")) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.EmailId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.EmailId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.EmailId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Gender)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Gender)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Gender)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.City)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.City)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Show_Users")
</div>
```

My Index Page Contains two fieldset one for login and another for Registration

### Show_Users.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<LoginOrRegisterDemo.Models.User>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Show_Users";
}

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Index", "Index")
</div>
```

### And Models are:-

### User.cs File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LoginOrRegisterDemo.Models
{
public class User : IUser
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public String EmailId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String City { get; set; }
}
public class IUser
{
    [Required]
    public String EmailId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
public class UserModel
{
    //public IEnumerable<LoginOrRegisterDemo.Models.User> users { get; set; }
    public User user;
    public IUser iuser;
}
}
```

### UserContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace LoginOrRegisterDemo.Models
{
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> users
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Register` action should look like this:

```
public void Register(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("Index");

    UserContext userContext = new UserContext();
    userContext.users.Add(user);
    userContext.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ShowUsers")
}
```

First, you check if your Model has any validation errors (`ModelState.IsValid`). If it does, the Action doesn't continue with the registration process, and returns a View instead.

When that View is being rendered, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` is able to show the error message using the errors data that is already collected and stored on the `ModelState` dictionary.

But, if upon validation failure you're performing a redirection (another HTTP GET request) then the rendered View doesn't have the necessary data on the `ModelState` dictionary since it already lost the original validation context.

Also, explicitly calling `Response.Redirect` is not the 'MVC' way to redirect, you better try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ShowUsers")
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: Inspite can you tell me how to use a model in single view for login as well as registration and with Validation... That will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show client side validation then check that your view contain this javascript

```
<script src="../../Script/Jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Script/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Script/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and if you have to show server side validation then do this,

```
Public ActionResult Register(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   
      UserContext userContext = new UserContext();
      userContext.users.Add(user);
      userContext.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("ShowUsers");
     }
  return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Index form has "UserModel" as model but how ever I want to pass "User"   as a model in it so is there any way to do that or I should drop the idea of Implementing Registration and login at same view...

Answer (score 0):

Got It

### HomeController

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index_Get()
    {
       return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index_Post(User user, IUser iuser, string Create)
    {
        if (Create == "Login")
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TryUpdateModel(iuser);
                UserContext userContext = new UserContext();
                User iusr = userContext.users.Single(usr1 => usr1.EmailId == iuser.EmailId);
                return RedirectToAction("Success", iusr);
            }
            return View();
        }
        if (Create == "Register")
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UserContext userContext = new UserContext();
                userContext.users.Add(user);
                userContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Show_Users");
            }
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Success")]
    public string Success(User iusr)
    {

        return "Welcome "+ iusr.Name;
    }
```

And Index should should be posted to Index Action

### Thank You For Replying buddies. It was Of great Help. GD